# Mark accepted answers on side panel

Tags: feature-request, design

The sidebar next to each question shows miscellaneous related/unrelated questions. On [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/727809/nginx-serve-different-files-using-try-files-based-on-cookies-conditions-if), it's clear which of those have accepted answers, because there's a box around the vote count:

[image]

Here there's no way to tell:

[image]

The Server Fault styling looks pretty much the same as on the main page, so we could do the same too -- mark posts with accepted answered green, unanswered gray. This would improve readability of the site and make things easier.

Answer (score 9):

There is actually a style that applies the color (`answered-accepted`), but then another one overrides it; I can't tell if this is intentional or not. This is what it looks like with the color coming through:

[image]

I'm not sure if it stands out enough, but it's definitely visible. I'm definitely for some sort of indicator though

Comment: Wow.  If you hadn’t pointed out that one of these things was different from the others, I wouldn’t have noticed.  BTW, thanks for posting the screenshot.  (I was going to do it; you beat me to it and saved me the effort.)

Comment: Firstly, thanks for adding screenshots. Secondly, I think that we should change background colour instead of number's colour - this would be much more visible.

Comment: That's hardly visible in your screenshot and it doesn't seem to work for linked answers. See, for example, [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123147/22222). There is one linked post which has an accepted answer but no indication of that.